# How do I report a user who has not posted and has an “about me” section full of spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

A few minutes ago, I came upon [this user](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/22023/user125766) whose About Me section was an advertisement.

The user has not created any posts.

How do I report this user? Other questions said to flag any post as moderator attention required and to explain to the moderators what happened, but this user has not created any posts.